# Get value from input textbox inside table and send to json stringify

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

This form grabs the input of the userID to get the list of vehicles assigned, then user will need to enter the mileage of each vehicle displayed in the table and the list will be saved with the mileage entered, the problem that I'm having is I cannot grab the mileage that I need to send to the database, the stringify comes "" when I send it to the codebehind. I'd appreciate any suggestions or pointing to the right direction.

--Javascript--

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.tabletojson.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
 //Get the User ID input

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSearch').click(function () {
            // alert("something");

            userInfo();
        });

        function userInfo() {
            var elem_id = $("#txtIBMEntry").val();
            var page_url = "MileageEntry.aspx/GetServices";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: page_url,
                data: "{'IBM':'" + elem_id + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (userDetails)
                { $("#infoDisplay").html(userDetails.d); }

            });

            //return false;
        };


        $('#btnSave').click(function () {

            // alert("This is going to activate the save procedure");

            setVehicleMileage();

        });

        function setVehicleMileage() {

            var page_urlSave = "MileageEntry.aspx/SetVehicleMileage";
            //var tbl = $('#results tr');
            var tbl = $('#results').tableToJSON();
            var table = JSON.stringify(tbl);


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: page_urlSave,
                data: "{'tbl':'" + table + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (userDetails1)
                { $("#infoDisplay").html(userDetails1.d); }

            });
            //alert(JSON.stringify(table));


        };

    });



</script>
```

this is how I load the html table, I'm using the same code to display the textboxes to enter mileage

```
   Public Shared Function GetString(ByVal IBM As String)
    'vb code 
   Dim ds As New DataSet

    IBM = Right("00000" & IBM, 5)

    ds = DBMgr.GetAssignedVeh(IBM)

    Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable()
    table = ds.Tables(0)

    Dim drows As DataRowCollection = table.Rows
    Dim HTML As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
    ' HTML.AppendLine("<table>")

    If drows.Count > 0 Then

        HTML.Append("<table id='results' style='border-width:1; border-color:Silver; border-style:solid; padding:4;'>")
        HTML.Append("<thead>")
        HTML.Append("<tr><th>Name/IBM</th><th>Vehicle </th><th>Vehicle Number</th><th>Mileage</th>")
        HTML.Append("</tr>")
        HTML.Append("</thead>")


        For Each dr As DataRow In drows
            HTML.Append("<tbody>")
            HTML.AppendLine("<tr>")
            HTML.AppendFormat("<td>{0}&nbsp&nbsp</td>" & vbLf, dr("AssignedIBM"))
            HTML.AppendFormat("<td>{0}&nbsp&nbsp</td>" & vbLf, dr("VehicleName"))
            HTML.AppendFormat("<td>{0}&nbsp</td>" & vbLf, dr("VehNum"))
            HTML.AppendFormat("<td>{0}&nbsp<input id='txtMileageEntry'/></td>" & vbLf, "")
            HTML.AppendLine("</tr>")


        Next
        HTML.AppendLine("<tr>")
        HTML.AppendLine("<td colspan=3> </td>")
        HTML.AppendLine("<td></td>")
        HTML.AppendLine("</tr>")
    HTML.Append("</tbody>")
        HTML.AppendLine("</table>")
        'HTML.AppendLine("</div>")
        '<input type='button' id='btnSave1' value='Save Mileage' />

    Else : HTML.AppendLine("<label id='lblMessage'style='color:Red ;' >IBM Entered does not match any records, Please try again.</label>")

    End If

    Return HTML.ToString


End Function
```

Comment: Oh it's so cute to see nub code like this! Been years! Ok, personal lolz aside, I think what you're looking for is [***here***](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/). And no offense meant, honestly great job including code on your question. I'm just tickled to see code so nice and clean and *long*.

Comment: Oh and welcome to Stack and VB ASP .Oops ... erm,  I mean .Net

Comment: Another thing that might help you in future: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/698246/ASP-NET-MVC-Special-Views-Partial-View-and-Layout -Not sure it's the best article on it, but it looks well written and seems to go in the right direction. Anyway, learn to make view partials in MVC (asp uses MVC) and you don't have to build such long strings like that. You can actually build HTML and call it in as needed.